# How can I use an external style sheet for an xml document

Tags: xml

I create multiple xml forms. I have button style that I use for every one of them (gel buttons). I am trying to find a way to put the styles in a separate sheet, similar to CSS with HTML, but this is only an xml sheet. I have seen several examples to link and show as html, or using app.xaml for wpf forms, but I don't use C# or html, only the xml (to be called by Powershell scripts). I do use VS wpf to build the xml, but only so I can see it visually while building; I don't use any other aspect of Visual studio in this case.
So, is there a way to link an xml style sheet to an xml document? My sanitized code is below (items like labels and gridsplitters removed, as I am only interested in the buttons here)

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="xml Tool"
        Height="200"
        Width="450">
    <Window.Resources>
<!-- Styles would go here. I want to replace this with a link to an external 
xml sheet with the styles, so I don't have to put it in every xml file -->
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- the rest of my xml -->
    <Grid Margin="2,2,2,2"
         Background="Cornsilk">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- unneeded items removed for length -->
        <Button x:Name="startButton"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Content="Confirm Selection"
                Margin="0,5,0,5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="25"
                Background="Green"
                Foreground="White"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                FontSize="16"
                Style="{DynamicResource GelButton}">
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cancelButton"
                Margin="0,5,0,5"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Content="Cancel"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="25"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                FontSize="16"
                Background="Firebrick"
                Foreground="White"
                Style="{DynamicResource GelButton}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And in case it is needed, my styles (only for buttons currently)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- For any buttons -->
    <Style x:Key="ShadowStyle">
        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground"
                 Value="LightGray" />
    </Style>
    <!-- Create the gel button -->
    <Style TargetType="Button"
             x:Key="GelButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                        <!-- drop shadow - needs to be blurred for correct effect -->
                        <Rectangle Fill="#40000000"
                                Margin="1,1,0,0"
                                RadiusX="6"
                                RadiusY="6">
                            <Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                                <BlurBitmapEffect Radius="3" />
                            </Rectangle.BitmapEffect>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <Grid x:Name="mainButton"
                           Margin="0,0,1,1"
                           Opacity="1.0"
                           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="0.0"
                                                  Y="0.0" />
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.0"
                                              ScaleY="1.0" />
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="mainRect"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                   RadiusX="6"
                                   RadiusY="6">
                            </Rectangle>

                            <!-- transparent rect -->
                            <Rectangle x:Name="glowRect"
                                   Margin="1,1,1,1"
                                   RadiusX="5"
                                   RadiusY="5">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                                   EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0"
                                               Color="#EFFFFFFF" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1"
                                               Color="#00FFFFFF" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          Margin="4,0,4,0"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                              Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="mainButton"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0.0"
                                                     Y="0.0" />
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.03"
                                                 ScaleY="1.03" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="#FF4788c8" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                              Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="mainButton"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="1"
                                                     Y="1" />
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.03"
                                                 ScaleY="1.03" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                              Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="mainButton"
                                Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.97"
                                                 ScaleY="0.97" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                Value="0.4" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```